# How do I update a list to all 0's in python

Tags: python

I'm doing a school project in which I'm making a movie theatre booking system. The database is stored in a csv file, in which 0's represent available seats and 1's represent booked seats. I want to add an option to convert all the values in the database to 0. I want to update the same csv file btw, not create another one.

```
with open('seats.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
seats = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
```

This is the code I used to import the database btw.

Thanks in advance for your help. I know this might be a basic question but I just started with python so I don't have much experience.

Comment: Just use pandas https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/replacing-column-value-of-a-csv-file-in-python/

Comment: CSV isn't good for partial updates.  If you need partial updates, it's better to use a binary file where the offset is computed from the seat number (and seek before writing), or use a database (a simple key-value store like gdbm is more than up to the job, or if you prefer you could use SQL or SQLAlchemy).

Answer (score 0):

You should use pandas for this. You can set values of columns and rows to 0 using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("seats.csv")
for col in df.columns:
    df[col].values[:] = 0
```

If you dont use Pandas, then use in native lists:

```
seats = [0 for x in seats]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> sample = []
>>> sample = [0] * 5
>>> sample
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: assuming `sample = [1,0,1,0,1]` I would recommend `sample = [0] * len(sample)` or `sample = [0 for i in sample]`

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you show us the exact codes for that.
I have an idea how to but it would be difficult for you if you dont show the codes

```
for eachSeat in seats:
    eachSeat = 0;
```

after this line you can open the file and write the seats list again to overwrite the file

Answer (score 0):

This'll do it:

```
import csv

with open('seats.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    seats = list(csv.reader(csvfile))

print(seats)

for row in seats:
    for i in range(len(row)):
        row[i] = '0'

print(seats)

with open('seats.csv', newline='', mode='w') as csvfile:
    csv.writer(csvfile).writerows(seats)
```

Results:

```
[['0', '1', '0', '1'], ['0', '0', '1', '1'], ['1', '1', '1', '1']]
[['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0']]
```